# Solution for route or path marking with bends

Tags: html5-canvas, bezier, curve, konvajs

I want to give my users an easy way to visually trace a route on a map or a picture. The solution must let the users add control points that they can use to put bends into the route.

It should work with html5 canvas - I currently use the Konvajs library so a solution that uses this would be good.

In the interests of sharing & learning, if you can suggest solutions using other HTML5 canvas libraries that would be good to see too.

*Note: This is not the original question posed. However it emerged over time that this was the actual requirement. The OP asked for means to find an arbitrary  point part way along a line / curve in an HTML5 canvas so that a draggable control point could be added at that point to edit the line / curve. The accepted answer does not meet this need. However, an answer to this original question would involve serious collision-detection math and potentially use of bezier control points - in other words it would be a big ask whilst the accepted answer is a very approachable solution with consistent UX.*

*The original question can be seen in via the edit links below this question.*

Comment: What is the intended UX for the knot - is it to become a handle for 'bending' the stick of the arrow?

Comment: Yea. It is to be able to manipulate the arrow so that it can go wherever the user takes it on a map for example by adding multiple knots.

Comment: ok - so like they were showing a route on a map - start from here, turn left here...turn right there...etc?  Where I see this done in other apps the user clicks a point to drop a map-pin (the finish point) and the line extends as a straight line to that point. There is then a small 'knot' half way between the last point and the pin, and the user can drag the knot to make a curve.  The effect is to let the user bend the route line around curves in the route and sharp bends. Is that it?

Comment: If you have a question about adding code, please also show the code you already have (in [mcve] form).

Comment: Ah, that could work. Right now I click and drag to create a two point arrow. The step I was originally thinking to edit it was to double click to go into edit mode to add more knots. But as per suggestion, maybe just click on the canvas to create the points as you go to create the final arrow, then you would have editable points to play around in the end. No adding new points is possible, but you probably have enough points to play with anyway to do minor edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this idea. You click where you want the next point and the route line extends with new positioning handles along the line segments. If you need arrows you can extend the objects herein as you require. You can easily change colours, stroke width, circle opacity etc with attributes of the route class. The points are available in an array and in the standard Konva.js line points list. The JS is vanilla, no other libraries needed or used.

The Export button shows how to grab the (x,y) fixed point objects for export purposes.

Example video here, working code in below snippet.

[image]

```js
// Set up the canvas / stage
var s1 = new Konva.Stage({container: 'container1', width: 600, height: 300});

// Add a layer for line
var lineLayer = new Konva.Layer({draggable: false});
s1.add(lineLayer);

// Add a layer for drag points
var pointLayer = new Konva.Layer({draggable: false});
s1.add(pointLayer);

// Add a rectangle to layer to catch events. Make it semi-transparent 
var r = new Konva.Rect({x:0, y: 0,  width: 600, height: 300, fill: 'black', opacity: 0.1})
pointLayer.add(r)

// Everything is ready so draw the canvas objects set up so far.
s1.draw()

// generic canvas end



// Class for the draggable point
// Params: route = the parent object, opts = position info, doPush = should we just make it or make it AND store it
var DragPoint = function(route, opts, doPush){
  var route = route;

  this.x = opts.x;
  this.y = opts.y;
  this.fixed = opts.fixed;
  this.id = randId();  // random id.

  if (doPush){  // in some cases we want to create the pt then insert it in the run of the array and not always at the end
    route.pts.push(this);  
  }

  // random id generator
  function randId() {
     return Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '').substr(2, 10);
  }

  // mark the pt as fixed - important state, shown by filled point
  this.makeFixed = function(){
    this.fixed = true;
    s1.find('#' + this.id)
        .fill(route.fillColor);      
  }
  
  this.kill = function(){
    s1.find('#' + this.id)
        .remove();        
  }
  
  this.draw = function(){
    // Add point & pt
    var circleId = this.id;
 
    var pt = new Konva.Circle({
      id: circleId,
      x: this.x, 
      y: this.y, 
      radius: route.pointRadius,
      opacity: route.pointOpacity,
      strokeWidth: 2,
      stroke: route.strokeColor,
      fill: 'transparent',
      draggable: 'true'    
    })
    pt.on('dragstart', function(){
        route.drawState = 'dragging';
    })
    pt.on('dragmove', function(){
      var pos = this.getPosition();
      route.updatePt(this.id(), pos)
      route.calc(this.id());
      route.draw();
    })
    pt.on('dragend', function(){

      route.drawState = 'drawing';
      var pos = this.getPosition();

      route.updatePt(this.getId(), pos);

      route.splitPts(this.getId());
      
      route.draw();
    })

    if (this.fixed){
      this.makeFixed();
    }
    
    
    route.ptLayer.add(pt);
    route.draw();

  }  
  
}

var Route = function() {

    this.lineLayer = null;
    this.ptLayer = null;
    this.drawState = '';

    this.fillColor = 'Gold';
    this.strokeColor = 'Gold';
    this.pointOpacity = 0.5;
    this.pointRadius = 10;
    this.color = 'LimeGreen';
    this.width = 5;
  
    this.pts = []; // array of dragging points.

    this.startPt = null;
    this.endPt = null;

    // reset the points 
    this.reset = function(){
      for (var i = 0; i < this.pts.length; i = i + 1){
        this.pts[i].kill();
      }
      this.pts.length = 0;
      this.draw();
    }

    // Add a point to the route.
    this.addPt = function(pos, isFixed){ 
      
      if (this.drawState === 'dragging'){  // do not add a new point because we were just dragging another
        return null;
      }
      
      this.startPt = this.startPt || pos;
      this.endPt = pos;

      // create this new pt
      var pt = new DragPoint(this, {x: this.endPt.x, y: this.endPt.y, fixed: isFixed}, true, "A");
      pt.draw();
      pt.makeFixed(); // always fixed for manual points
      
      // if first point ignore the splitter process
      if (this.pts.length > 0){
        this.splitPts(pt.id, true);
      }    

      this.startPt = this.endPt; // remember the last point

      this.calc(); // calculate the line points from the array
      this.draw();  // draw the line 
    }

  // Position the points.  
  this.calc = function (draggingId){
    draggingId = (typeof draggingId === 'undefined' ? '---' : draggingId); // when dragging an unfilled point we have to override its automatic positioning.

    for (var i = 1; i < this.pts.length - 1; i = i + 1){

      var d2 = this.pts[i];
      if (!d2.fixed && d2.id !== draggingId){      // points that have been split are fixed, points that have not been split are repositioned mid way along their line segment.

        var d1 = this.pts[i - 1];
        var d3 = this.pts[i + 1];
        var pos = this.getHalfwayPt(d1, d3);
        
        d2.x = pos.x;
        d2.y = pos.y;
      }
      s1.find('#' + d2.id).position({x: d2.x, y: d2.y}); // tell the shape where to go
    }
  }

  // draw the line
  this.draw = function (){  

    if (this.drawingLine){
      this.drawingLine.remove();
    }
    this.drawingLine = this.newLine(); // initial line point
    
    for (var i = 0; i < this.pts.length; i = i + 1){
      this.drawingLine.points(this.drawingLine.points().concat([this.pts[i].x, this.pts[i].y]))
    }
    
    this.ptLayer.draw();
    this.lineLayer.draw();
  }

  // When dragging we need to update the position of the point
  this.updatePt = function(id, pos){

      for (var i = 0; i < this.pts.length; i = i + 1){
        if (this.pts[i].id === id){

          this.pts[i].x = pos.x;
          this.pts[i].y = pos.y;

          break;
        }    
      }
  }

  // Function to add and return a line object. We will extend this line to give the appearance of drawing.
  this.newLine = function(){
    var line = new Konva.Line({
        stroke: this.color,
        strokeWidth: this.width,
        lineCap: 'round',
        lineJoin: 'round',
        tension : .1
      });

    this.lineLayer.add(line)
    return line;
  }  


  // make pts either side of the split
  this.splitPts = function(id, force){
    var idx = -1;
    
    // find the pt in the array
    for (var i = 0; i < this.pts.length; i = i + 1){
      if (this.pts[i].id === id){
        idx = i;

        if (this.pts[i].fixed && !force){
          return null; // we only split once.
        }

        //break;
      }   
    }

    // If idx is -1 we did not find the pt id !
    if ( idx === -1){
      return null
    }
    else if (idx === 0  ) { 
      return null
    }
    else { // pt not = 0 or max 

      // We are now going to insert a new pt either side of the one we just dragged
      var d1 = this.pts[idx - 1]; // previous pt to the dragged pt
      var d2 = this.pts[idx    ]; // the pt pt
      var d3 = this.pts[idx + 1]; // the next pt after the dragged pt

      d2.makeFixed()// flag this pt as no longer splittable

      // get point midway from prev pt and dragged pt    
      var pos = this.getHalfwayPt(d1, d2);
      var pt = new DragPoint(this, {x: pos.x, y: pos.y, foxed: false}, false, "C");
      pt.draw();
      this.pts.splice(idx, 0, pt);

      if (d3){
        // get point midway from dragged pt to next     
        pos = this.getHalfwayPt(d2, d3);
        var pt = new DragPoint(this, {x: pos.x, y: pos.y, foxed: false}, false, "D");
        pt.draw();
        this.pts.splice(idx + 2, 0, pt); // note idx + 2 !

      }

    }  

  }  
  
  // convert last point array entry to handy x,y object.
  this.getPoint = function(pts){
    return {x: pts[pts.length - 2], y: pts[pts.length - 1]};
  }
  
  this.getHalfwayPt = function(d1, d2){
    var pos = {
          x: d1.x + (d2.x - d1.x)/2, 
          y: d1.y + (d2.y - d1.y)/2
      }
    return pos;
  }

  this.exportPoints = function(){
    var list = [], pt;    
    console.log('pts=' + this.pts.length)
    for (var i = 0; i < this.pts.length; i = i + 1){      
      pt = this.pts[i]
      if (pt.fixed){
        console.log('push ' + i)
        list.push({x: pt.x, y: pt.y});   
      }   
    }  
    return list;
  }
  
}

var route = new Route();
route.lineLayer = lineLayer;
route.ptLayer = pointLayer;

route.fillColor = 'AliceBlue'; 
route.strokeColor = 'Red'; 
route.pointOpacity = 0.5;
route.pointRadius = 7;
route.color = '#2982E8'


// Listen for mouse up on the stage to know when to draw points
s1.on('mouseup touchend', function () {

  route.addPt(s1.getPointerPosition(), true);

  
  
});

// jquery is used here simply as a quick means to make the buttons work.

// Controls for points export
$('#export').on('click', function(){

  if ($(this).html() === "Hide"){
    $(this).html('Export');
    $('#points').hide();
  }
  else {
    $(this).html('Hide');
    $('#points')
      .css('display', 'block')
      .val(JSON.stringify(route.exportPoints()));
  }  

})

// reset button
$('#reset').on('click', function(){
  route.reset();
  })
```

```css
p
{
  padding: 4px;
}
#container1
{
background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/gADDJ.png');
}
#ctrl
{
position: absolute;
z-index: 10;
margin: 0px;
border: 1px solid red;
}
#points
{
width: 500px;
height: 100px;
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konvajs/konva/1.6.5/konva.min.js"></script>
<p>Click to add a point, click to add another, drag a point to make a bend, etc.
</p>
<div id='ctrl'>
<button id='reset'>Reset</button>
<button id='export'>Export</button>
<textarea id='points'></textarea>
</div>
<div id='container1' style="display: inline-block; width: 300px, height: 200px; background-color: silver; overflow: hidden; position: relative;"></div>
<div id='img'></div>
```

Comment: This is fantastic! Exactly what I described:) thank you!! I will probably play with the code a little bit and see how I get on and learn from this as well. Thanks again!

Comment: @Huy - Thanks glad to help. Couple of points - first please could you mark my answer as correct so as to help future folks searching for help to judge the quality, and second would you mind if I edited your question to make it a bit more representative of the generic requirement for 'marking a route or path on a canvas'. Again this is for future folk looking for something similar who may not recognise your question as being the same subject.

Comment: I marked it as correct and no problem with you modifying the original post. Thanks a bunch!