# Animate a shape along a line or path in konva

Tags: html5-canvas, konvajs, react-konva

Is it possible in Konva to animate a shape (marker, circle) along a lline/path. I tried to manually calculate positions over time but this is only feasible if the line is straight from A to B, but I'm interested in a bezier curve and multiple path points.

So I wonder if Konva supports this kind of thing or someone could give a direction how to approach this.

Comment: Okay, basically using getPointAtLength(length) and getLength() should allow to get a position of a point on a graph… which then could be animated:
https://konvajs.github.io/api/Konva.Path.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have identified, the Path object has some handy methods in getLength() to find the overall path length and getPointAtLength() which can then be used to find the (x,y) at any given point along the length.

In case it helps anyone, I built the path data from the output of [another snippet from this other question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53055061/solution-for-route-or-path-marking-with-bends/53103962#53103962)

```js
var data = [{"x":34,"y":34},{"x":84,"y":64},{"x":141,"y":79},{"x":181.5,"y":78.5},{"x":218,"y":62},{"x":223,"y":40},{"x":240,"y":26},{"x":259.5,"y":25},{"x":271,"y":40},{"x":292.5,"y":53},{"x":311.25,"y":55.5},{"x":330.625,"y":46.75},{"x":332.3125,"y":30.375},{"x":349.15625,"y":10.1875},{"x":374.578125,"y":10.09375},{"x":392,"y":26},{"x":411,"y":36},{"x":444.5,"y":37},{"x":453.875,"y":27.25},{"x":463.25,"y":17.5},{"x":472.9375,"y":10.625},{"x":494.625,"y":15.75},{"x":530,"y":48},{"x":534,"y":88},{"x":540,"y":150},{"x":552,"y":198},{"x":544,"y":227},{"x":522,"y":256},{"x":504.5,"y":263},{"x":471,"y":262},{"x":448,"y":252},{"x":372,"y":214},{"x":290,"y":146},{"x":256,"y":100},{"x":198,"y":104},{"x":182,"y":140},{"x":204,"y":185},{"x":203,"y":201.5},{"x":190,"y":214},{"x":174.5,"y":218},{"x":155,"y":214},{"x":124,"y":222},{"x":113.5,"y":232.5},{"x":95,"y":227},{"x":75.5,"y":211.5},{"x":72,"y":188},{"x":58,"y":136}]

// Set up the canvas / stage
var stage = new Konva.Stage({container: 'container1', width: 600, height: 300});

// Add a layer for line
var layer = new Konva.Layer({draggable: false});
stage.add(layer);

// draw a path.
    var path = new Konva.Path({
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      stroke: 'cyan'
    });
layer.add(path)

// Load the path points up using M = moveto, L = lineto.
var p = "M" + data[0].x + " " + data[0].y;
for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i = i + 1){
  p = p + " L" + data[i].x + " " + data[i].y;
}
path.setData(p);

// add a circle to be animated along the path
var circle = new Konva.Circle({ x: data[0].x, y: data[0].y, radius: 10, fill: 'Magenta'});
layer.add(circle);

stage.draw();

$('#reset').on('click', function(){

  // Now animate a circle along the path
  var steps = 50; // number of steps in animation
  var pathLen = path.getLength();
  var step = pathLen / steps;
  var frameCnt = 0, pos =0, pt;

    anim = new Konva.Animation(function(frame) {
        pos = pos + 1;
        pt = path.getPointAtLength(pos * step);
        circle.position({x: pt.x, y: pt.y});    
    }, layer);

  anim.start();
})

$('#reset').trigger('click');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/konva/2.5.1/konva.min.js"></script>
<button style='position: absolute; z-index: 10;' id='reset'>Go</button>
<div id='container1' style="width: 300px, height: 200px; background-color: silver;"></div>
<div id='img'></div>
```

Comment: thank you so much for this clear and detailed answer, especially for also referencing the other snippet. much appreciated.